# Use Scala function instead of a Java callback-like anonymous object

Tags: java, scala, callback, anonymous-function

Java-style anonymous callbacks include relatively much boilerplate and are not pleasing to read. It would be nice to have something like

```
workExpression
```

instead of

```
new SomeIF {
    @Override public someType doRun() {
        return workExpression
    }
}
```

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: @Arne: I edited and added explicit question, but implicitly it could have been inferred. I could write a blog entry or else, but I added this on SO (and one answer I found) in order to 1) share it 2) collect more knowledge on it from others.

Comment: Apparently someone already blogged about this (http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/blog/simulating-sam-closures-scala), but I couldn't find it in google as I didn't know it was called SAM Closure until Alexey's post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is using `implicit` defs for converting functions to the legacy callback types. For example:

```
// Required by some API
trait Callable[A] {
  def call(): A
}

trait Processor[A,B] {
  def process(a: A): B
}

// Our helper trait
trait MyImplicits {
  implicit def funToCallable[A](f: () => A) = new Callable[A]() { 
    def call() = f()
  }

  implicit def funToProcessor[A,B](f: (A) => B) = new Processor[A,B]() {
    def process(a: A) = f(a)
  }

}

object App extends MyImplicits {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Traditional usage
    runSomeCallable(new Callable[String]() {
      def call() = "World"
    })

    runSomeProcessor(new Processor[String,Int] {
      def process(a: String) = a.toInt * 2
    })

    // Usage with implicits
    runSomeCallable(() => "Scala World")

    runSomeProcessor((s: String) => s.toInt * 2)
  }

  // Methods defined by some foreign API
  def runSomeCallable[A](callable: Callable[A]) {
    println("Hello "+callable.call())
  }

  def runSomeProcessor(processor: Processor[String,Int]) {
    println("From 1 to "+processor.process("1"))
  }

}
```

Therefore when working with some code, one could create a helper trait for the common callback types used in that code to ease readability.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic conversion of closures to interfaces with single methods may appear in a future version of Scala: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8744 This would avoid the boilerplate with implicits which is currently necessary.